# jQuery slider widget background -- change dynamicaly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use a custom background for my slider by overriding the CSS:

```
.ui-widget-content {background: transparent url(../img/bg.png) no-repeat;}
```

Slider's behavior is controlled by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myslider5").slider({
        animate: "true",
        step: 1,
        min: -1950,
        max: 1950,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
               // magic happens here
        }
    });
    $(".myslider3").slider({
        animate: "true",
        step: 1,
        min: -1350,
        max: 1350,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
               // magic happens here
        }
    });
```

So, `myslider5` and `myslider3` are the two classes. But their background images need to be different. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

**DEMO** http://jsbin.com/itivu3

**SOURCE** http://jsbin.com/itivu3/edit

**NOTE:** taking in mind what you have asked, *`change image dynamically  on slide!!!`*

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want to achieve. Sorry for the poor explanation. I am trying to use different backgrounds for each slider class.

Comment: this is just a proof of concept! it does just what you want! just use separately! see my update!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason, aSeptik's suggestion was not working. It had to be tweaked in the CSS section and not in the JS.

```
.myslider5.ui-widget-content {background: transparent url(../img/slider5.png);}
.myslider3.ui-widget-content {background: transparent url(../img/slider3.png);}
```

Comment: it is working fine dude! the problem is that i have used the css you have provided to me! just use `url(../img/myslider5.png)` instead of
`url(../img/myslider5.png) no-repeat;` see the updates!

Comment: @aSeptik No, I had to update the CSS file with the above lines, and not the JS file.

Comment: I have update with a demo so you can understand what i mean! ;-) and peraphs can learn something more!